# How to set bootstrap column for mobile screen, medium screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

1. for medium screen

```
|-----(1)||-----(2)|
```

2. for mobile screen iphone x

```
|---------------(2)|
|-----(1)|
```

in first scenario both (1) and (2) have same column size in single line,
but in second scenario (1) and (2) both have in different line,

```
<div class="row">
<h3 class="col-7 col-md-6" >(1)</h3>
<h3 class="col-12 col-md-6" >(2)</h3>
</div>
```

but in second scenario (mobile screen) i am facing difficulty to set column, can any one help me for second scenario.

Answer (score 0):

### [Edited]

> Flex is the solution :)

You can use `flex` properties to make it easier, they're a little tricky at the beginning but very effective.

### Example

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="m-5">
  <h2>Option</h2>
  <div class="w-50 d-flex flex-column-reverse flex-md-row">
    <h3 class="col-7 col-md-6 border border-dark">(1)</h3>
    <h3 class="col-12 col-md-6 border border-dark">(2)</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have edited scenario where in mobile screen and medium screen size for both in single code, if first scenario then medium screen, if second scenario then mobile screen how do i write single code, can you please edit your answer, Thank you